# How do you say "beware the cats" in Japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

The Italians have the famous phrase "Attenti ai gatti". Is there something similar in Japan?

Would be good to have both the kanji and kana versions, since I am still a beginner. I can work out the romaji from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be 「猫{ねこ}に注意{ちゅうい}」-- 「ねこにちゅうい」 in all kana.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is plural, right? I'm not sure how Japanese handles plurals...

Comment: Japanese doesn't have plural forms of words the way English does, so this could be either plural or singular. :)